# Angularjs Formatar data

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, data, controller

Como formato a data no controller do input type="DATE"?

eu tenho esse retorno no controller...

```
Sat Aug 06 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)

Mon Aug 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
```

tem como formatar para

```
01-08-2016?
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) do angular.

**Edição** para alterar o formato da Data no Controller

Exemplo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.today = new Date();
    $scope.todayString = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyy');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

<p>Data = {{ today | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</p>
  
<p>Data direto do Controller = {{ todayString }}</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Nem me lembrava disso rsrs. +1. Pode colocar a função do js, `$filter`? apenas pra completar.

Comment: Não resolveu o problema, meu problema é no controller, preciso pegar essa informação no controller, não na view... quero usar o input como parâmetro para fazer uma requisição e no caso o formato da data que vem não está no formato que deveria estar... que no caso seria 01-08-2016

Comment: Editei, você poder usar o date filter do angular, tanto no JS quanto no bind do Html.

Answer (score 1):

Olá amigo tem uma ótima biblioteca javascript para formatação de data 
http://momentjs.com/

No seu controller ficaria assim 
moment(suaData).format('DD-MM-YYYY');

Documento da biblioteca 
http://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Se é dentro do controller do Angular, então deve-se criar um formatador usando apenas JavaScript.

[Segue a lista de referências de funções com data para JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

```
function pad(n) {
    return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
}

function formataMinhaData (data) {
    return pad(data.getDate()) + '/' + pad(data.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + data.getFullYear();
}
```